# SQL Database Admin or Developer?

Tags: database-administration, sqldeveloper

Can someone explain the main difference between each? Which one do you consider more difficult? Which one is it easier to find and maintain a job?

Im trying to start the first stepping stone of doing my certifications and learning more about MS-SQL 2008 but Im not sure which path to take? 
Any pointers/Tips are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL Database Administrator is primarily responsible for the aspects of keeping the system up and running, making sure its sustainable, redundant, secure and performing.
This would include doing things such as building/deploying the operating system the SQL server software have a strong understanding of storage, security + active directory since you mentioned MSSQL (Windows) and disaster recovery.  You will have day to day chores making sure backups are good, replication is replicating and performance is optimal.

Developers are responsible for the underlining databases themselves.   Writing the structures which include the tables, fields.  A developer should be strong in running and creating their own SPs (store procedures) as well as building various connectors to various platforms.

Between the 2 a developer has it made on job security and a repeatable process of success based on the outcome this will be the preferred job if you have programming experience.

A database administrator is a more glorified version of a windows system administrator with a fine tuned specialty which brings them a step up and a extremely high liability job since it is the database of an entire company in certain aspects that can cause major jeopardy.  In addition administrator sleeps less at night.  developer gets a good nights sleep.

Comment: addirionally db admins are usually tasked with desiging an infrastructure to support a given sql app based on load and expected performance